# how to resolve syntax error using copy command from s3 to redshift db

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

Syntax error in copy command from s3 to redshift

I can connect to the the redshift database but get syntax error at tablename of copy command.  I'm using a csv file in s3 to schema.tblname in redshift

```
COPY ###_schema.tblName_csv
FROM 's3://####/###/Filename.csv'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam::######'
DATEFORMAT 'auto'
IGNOREHEADER 1
DELIMITER ','
IGNOREBLANKLINES;
```

I'd like to be able to select * from this tbl after loading data

Comment: What is the error saying exactly?

Comment: it says code 8001, user not authorized to assume IAM Role.  I have given it the IAM provided to me and my own IAM credentials

Comment: I suspect that the role is not associated with your Redshift Cluster - have a look here to see how to associate it https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/authorizing-redshift-service.html

Comment: What do you mean by _and my own credentials_? You should provide either a role, or credentials.

Comment: from above credential line in the copy command given to me  arn:aws:iam::randomKey>:user/james.cole@<companyName>.com
'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam::<randomKey:role/<clusterName>-redshift-role'(provided)  I have an IAM role but in the copy command he provided something else which might be the problem.  At the start I set boto3.client to equal 'Redshift' to make the connection which I verify is true, when copying do i need another "Boto3.client" pointing to s3?

Comment: You don't execute `COPY` via boto, you do it via JDBC (sql) interface. You either have to pass credentials, or use a role associated with your Redshift cluster. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Redshift `COPY` command will require some way to get s3 permissions. You can

- provide that using either an IAM role (role [has to associated with your cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/authorizing-redshift-service.html)),

  ```
  copy customer from 's3://mybucket/mydata'  
  iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole';
  ```
- provide AWS access key and secret key

  ```
  copy table-name
  from 's3://objectpath'
  ACCESS_KEY_ID '<access-key-id>'
  SECRET_ACCESS_KEY '<secret-access-key>';
  ```
- provide temporary credentials from sts service

  ```
  copy table-name
  from 's3://objectpath'
  access_key_id '<temporary-access-key-id>'
  secret_access_key '<temporary-secret-access-key>
  token '<temporary-token>';
  ```

[Redshift Manual reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-access-permissions.html#copy-usage_notes-access-key-based)